A tablet with Gboard or similar multilingual semi-virtual-keyboard connectable to a Windows 11 Home PC
I need a tablet with Google Gboard or similar multilingual virtual keyboard connectable to a Windows 11 Home PC to use it as a keyboard instead of using a traditional regular QWERTY keyboard.
I don't care if this tablet is an entire computer with an operating system or just a virtual keyboard tablet. I just want Google Gboard or something similar to Google Gboard, with which I could switch languages easily, to type in the way that I am used to via my pocket computer.
